# Sybase Replace Function Issue

Tags: database, plsql, sybase, sap-ase

I have statement

```
SET @abc = 'ankit kumar'
SET @xyz = 'rohit'
SET @abc = SELECT REPLACE(@abc, 'ankit', @xyz)
```

but it not working and giving error:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
I have also tried below instead of 3rd line but it doesn't work either:

```
SET @abc = REPLACE(@abc, 'ankit', @xyz)
```

Please assist. I am using Sybase ASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @abc varchar(100)
declare @xyz varchar(100)

SET @abc = 'ankit kumar'
SET @xyz = 'rohit'
set @abc =  str_replace(@abc, 'ankit', @xyz)
```

Comment: I have posted full code from my ase15.0. please paste error that you are getting now.

Answer (score 0):

You have both "set" and "select" in the same statement. Choose one.

```
SET @abc = REPLACE(@abc, 'ankit', @xyz)
```

or

```
SELECT @abc = REPLACE(@abc, 'ankit', @xyz)
```